# Swift 'fabs' is deprecated: renamed to 'abs'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I try using fabs on a CGFloat number in Swift 5, I get this warning:

```
'fabs' is deprecated: renamed to 'abs'
```

But when I use abs, it's argument is only Integer, not Float or Double. I am using XCode 12 if that matters. How do I resolve this?

Comment: `abs(someCGFloat)` compiles without problems in my Xcode 12 and returns a `CGFloat`. Can you post a concrete example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: You should file a bug for this error message.

Comment: @MartinR Ok it points to inlinable public func abs<T>(_ x: T) -> T where T : Comparable, T : SignedNumeric

Comment: @DeepakSharma Provide [mcve] please. You know the drill: don't talk _about_ your code, _show_ your code. Thanks.

Comment: I think it was based on misunderstanding. I manually replaced the fabs with abs and then it showed argument as int. But when I pressed the dot button in yellow warning to autocorrect it, it took me to public func abs<T>(_ x: T) -> T where T : Comparable, T : SignedNumeric which is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably using `abs` from the Foundation framework.

Try the following:

```
Swift.abs(CGFloat(1.0))
```

---

```
Foundation.abs(CGFloat(1.0)) // Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'Int32'
```

```
Swift.abs(CGFloat(1.0)) // Compiles successfully
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`CGFloat.magnitude`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat/2299986-magnitude%60)

```
CGFloat(-1.23).magnitude // => 1.23
```